# How to use custom htmlwidget in ShinyApp? waypoints.js

Tags: javascript, r, jquery-waypoints, shiny

I have created an `htmlwidget` using the `waypoint.js`JavaScript Library.  However, I am not really sure how to transfer it into my ShinyApp.

I want to have an image consisting of 3-5 pieces, explode, similar to an exploded part assembly list when you're building furniture or a toy, when the mouse is moved over it.

In my `waypoint.R` file, I have the following:

```
waypoint <- function(message, width = NULL, height = NULL) {

  # forward options using x
  x = list(
    message = message
  )

  # create widget
  htmlwidgets::createWidget(
    name = 'waypoint',
    x,
    width = width,
    height = height,
    package = 'waypointR'
  )
}

waypointOutput <- function(outputId, width = '100%', height = '400px'){
  shinyWidgetOutput(outputId, 'waypoint', width, height, package = 'waypointR')
}
renderWaypoint <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
  if (!quoted) { expr <- substitute(expr) } # force quoted
  shinyRenderWidget(expr, waypointOutput, env, quoted = TRUE)
}
```

I also have an example javascript code, where someone used `waypoints.js`, but I'm not sure how to implement that into my R code.  That code is as follows:

```
    this.explode = function() {
        $('#top').animate({
            top:topTop
        },400, function() {
            // animation complete
            $('#tempWrapper').fadeIn(250);
        });
        $('#bottom').animate({
            top:bottomTop
        },400, function() {
            // animation complete
        });
    }
    this.implode = function() {
        $('#tempWrapper').fadeOut(250);
        $('#top').animate({
            top:middleTop
        },400, function() {
            // animation complete
            $('#tempWrapper').fadeOut(0);
        });
        $('#bottom').animate({
            top:middleTop
        },400, function() {
            // animation complete
        });
    }

 // Add Waypoints
$('#middle').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == "down") {
        this.implodeHouse();
    } else {
        this.explodeHouse();
    }
}.bind(this),{
    offset:'0%'
});
$('#middle').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == "down") {
        this.explode();
    } else {
        this.implode();
    }
}.bind(this),{
    offset:'50%'
});
```

My issue comes when I need to transfer this to my ShinyApp.  I'm not sure where to go, other than using `waypointOutput` and `renderWaypoint`.